# How to distinguish two "almost isomorphic" groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, computational-mathematics

I'd like to ask the following:

Let $G$ and $H$ be the two finite groups, which are not isomorphic, but "almost", i.e. they share a lot of common properties.

Let $G:=$SmallGroup(605,5) and $H:=$SmallGroup(605,6).

> How can you distinguish $G$ and $H$ in this case without just saying that IdSmallGroup($G$)$\neq$IdSmallGroup($H$)?

Of course, you could say that $G\cong H$, iff their group algebras are isomorphic as Hopf algebras.

But, concretely, I am searching for an invariant under isomorphism to distinguish them, such like $G'\not\cong H'$ or $G$ is abelian and $H$ is not or the number of conjugacy classes is different or the Frattini subgroups are not isomorphic, etc.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any invariant which distinguishes them by now.

I would be thankful for any help.

EDIT(10th March 2020): I changed the question, because it was closed for the following reason: This question needs to be more focused.

Comment: In fact, determining whether two finite groups are isomorphic is a difficult task in general.

Comment: In b) note that $G$ is mentioned in https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/241/C9.5He3.html and $H$ is https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/241/C9.6He3.html

Comment: There is no magic method. A classical start would be to look at their character tables, which does tell quite a bit about a group. I don't know if in your examples it would be enough to distinguish them, but I guess formal computation programs can look that up.

Comment: $G$ has a characteristic subgroup of order 11, $H$ does not.  Of course, why you would look at that is mostly just a "throw everything including the kitchen sink at it" thing, because you know the number and isomorphism types of characteristic subgroups is an isomorphism invariant, and is not terribly easy to establish I think.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. The OP is asking "my computer says these two groups are non-isomorphic and I want to know *why*", which seems to me to be a perfectly acceptable question...

Comment: @CaptainLama: Thank you very much for your comment. I let GAP calculate and compare the ordinary character tables, and GAP says that they are indeed different (after every row and column permutation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well-known fact that solvable groups are difficult to classify because of the abundance of normal subgroups. In a certain sense the class of groups of primepower order is the simplest case to handle. But already here the classification is far from being complete. Up to now there are only a few classes of such primepower order groups which have been adequately analysed.

The first to create
some order in the plethora of groups of prime-power order was Philip Hall. He
observed that the notion of *isomorphism* of groups is really too strong to give
rise to a satisfactory classification and that it had to be replaced by a weaker
equivalence relation. Subsequently he discovered a suitable equivalence relation
and called it *isoclinism* of groups (see Ph. Hall, *[The classification of prime-power groups](https://eudml.org/doc/150084)*, J. Reine Angew. Math. 182 (1940), 130-141.). It is this classification principle that underlies the famous monograph of M. Hall and J. K. Senior on the classification of 2-groups of order at most 64.

The isoclinism class of a group G is determined by the groups $G/Z(G)$ (the inner automorphism group) and $G′$ (the commutator subgroup) and the commutator map from $G/Z(G) \times G/Z(G)$ to $G’$. In other words, two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isoclinic if there are isomorphisms from $G_1/Z(G_1)$ to $G_2/Z(G_2)$ and from $G_1′$ to $G_2′$ commuting with the commutator map. See also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231971968_Varieties_of_groups_and_isologisms).